# Apache Flink: Periodically load configuration for a function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Let's say, There is dynamic configuration are stored in a DB to filter blacklisted events from the stream.

A filter function uses this configuration and needs to reload/refresh a new configuration after a time interval(10 min).

A function can be called in every window call to reload the config and reassign the config variable.

NOTE: As this function call in a window is independent of stream's events data so don't want to buffer/hold the stream events in memory till the window is triggered.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

You could put a ProcessFunction in front of the window, and have it do the filtering. I'm suggesting a ProcessFunction because it can have a timer that fires every 10 minutes to trigger the reload/refresh of the configuration data.

In this way, all of the events that reach the window will have been pre-filtered by the version of the droplist configuration that was active at the time each event was received.

You could take further advantage of streaming, and stream in the changes to the droplist configuration as they occur, rather than polling for them every 10 minutes.